# How to update Http Request and send it to another web server

Tags: iis-7, jboss, http-headers, isapi-redirect, isapi-extension

Following is our environment setup:

IIS 7 receives Http (.jsp) request from client (browser).
It blindly redirects it to JBoss using ISAPI_Redirect.dll.

Now we are trying to modify this setup in such a way that before IIS7/ISAPI_redirect sends it to JBoss, we need to modify posted form data using Http module. This http module is normal .net http module.

We are able to intercept the request @ BeginRequest event of http module and when we send it to JBoss, it gives us "Read client failed (400)" error.

Any idea how to achieve this task or fix the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were not able to fix our problem in its original form. What we did is we removed ISAPI_REDIRECT/JBoss from our original pipeline.

We now take the request directly to our http module by setting up another virtual directory where ISAPI_Redirect is not configured, we do our modification (earlier we intended to do this after JBoss has received the request) and then send it to another virtual directory (URL) where ISAPI_REDIRECT is configured. Now ISAPI_Redirect captures the request, maps it to JBoss format and sends it to JBoss.

Basically we switched the place of our customer processing and things seem to falling in place.